# SQL query is slow. How can I make it faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I have the following tables which is essentially a system to tell me who was in what room:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
    (`cus_id` int PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(5), `driver_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO customers
    (`cus_id`, `name`, `driver_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'bob', 11111),
    (2, 'james', 22222),
    (3, 'sam', 33333),
    (4, 'billy', 44444)
;


CREATE TABLE hotel_rooms
    (`hroom_id` int PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(10), `cus_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO hotel_rooms
    (`hroom_id`, `name`, `cus_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'small room', 3),
    (2, 'big room', 1)
;


CREATE TABLE snapshots
    (`snapshot_id` int PRIMARY KEY, `hroom_id` int, FOREIGN KEY (hroom_id) REFERENCES hotel_rooms (hroom_id), `date_added` datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO snapshots
    (`snapshot_id`, `hroom_id`, `date_added`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2020-01-12 12:43:13'),
    (2, 1, '2020-01-13 17:23:53'),
    (3, 2, '2020-01-19 07:34:01')
;


CREATE TABLE participants
    (`participant_id` int PRIMARY KEY, `snapshot_id` int, FOREIGN KEY (snapshot_id) REFERENCES snapshots (snapshot_id), `cus_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO participants
    (`participant_id`, `snapshot_id`, `cus_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 3),
    (3, 2, 1),
    (4, 2, 2),
    (5, 2, 3),
    (6, 3, 1),
    (7, 3, 4)
;
```

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT s.snapshot_id, 
       hr.name, 
       c1.driver_id AS owner_driver_id,
       md.max_date AS date_added,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c2.driver_id) AS participants_driver_ids 
FROM snapshots s
JOIN (
  SELECT hr.hroom_id, MAX(date_added) AS max_date
  FROM hotel_rooms hr
  JOIN snapshots s ON s.hroom_id = hr.hroom_id
  JOIN participants p ON p.snapshot_id = s.snapshot_id
  JOIN customers c ON c.cus_id = p.cus_id
  WHERE c.cus_id = 1
  GROUP BY hr.hroom_id, hr.name
) md ON md.hroom_id = s.hroom_id AND md.max_date = s.date_added
JOIN hotel_rooms hr ON hr.hroom_id = s.hroom_id
JOIN customers c1 ON c1.cus_id = hr.cus_id
JOIN participants p ON p.snapshot_id = s.snapshot_id
JOIN customers c2 ON c2.cus_id = p.cus_id
GROUP BY s.snapshot_id, hr.name, c1.driver_id, md.max_date
;
```

---

SQL code of tables and statement: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6844de/1

Desired output:
[image]

Essentially what the participant table says is:

- `snapshot_id=1` `bob` and `sam` where in `small room`.
- `snapshot_id=2`, `bob`, `james` and `sam` where in `small room`.
- `snapshot_id=3`, `bob` and `billy` where in `big room`.

Execution plan:
[image]

However the query is slow. I don't understand what I need to index to make this query faster because they are all basically join statements.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan? It should be included in your post.

Comment: Did you add any constraints? Try adding primary key constraint to the ID columns of each table followed by a foreign key references

Comment: @Govind Sorry, I updated my sql code to add primary keys and foreign keys. My actual implementation has these constraints

Comment: @KenWhite How do i find it

Comment: Understand that you have a query which is slow. However, would it be possible to mention what is the desired output that you are looking for here so that it might be easier to recommend an alternative approach that might be simpler instead of debugging the existing query.

Comment: [Optimizing queries with EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN EXTENDED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: @Somy Updated my question

Comment: @KenWhite I've updated my question with an sql fiddle which shows execution plan

Comment: The information needs to be here, in the question itself. You can use SQL Fiddle as an additional resource, but the relevant information needs to be in this question. See the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite I have updated with everything

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATETIME`, not `VARCHAR` for datetime values.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...`

Experiment with the subquery -- this will help decide whether the sluggishness is with the subquery or the rest.

`snapshot` needs a composite index `INDEX(hroom, date_added)` with the columns in that order.

Comment: It is the exact same keys as the execution plan

Comment: So I added a lot of indexes and what not. The query is now fast. However, the subquery (aka the derived table)'s type is `ALL` in the `EXPLAIN SELECT`. How can I speed up the derived table? Maybe subqueries is the best way to go? Is there a way I can re-write the statement without a subquery?

Comment: @James - The fiddle has so few rows in each table that I worry about the `EXPLAIN`.  For example, since 25% of the rows are `cus_id=1`, the Optimizer is likely to do a table scan instead of using an index.

Answer (score 0):

The query selects all snapshots made the same day customer #1 had the last snapshot for the same hotel room.

I'd probably write the subquery as

```
SELECT hroom_id, MAX(date_added) AS max_date
FROM snapshots s
WHERE snapshot_id IN (SELECT snapshot_id FROM participants WHERE cus_id = 1)
GROUP BY hroom_id
```

This gets the intention clear and I removed two tables that are not needed for this evaluation.

Indexes for this subquery:

```
create index idx1 on participants (cus_id, snapshot_id);
create index idx2 on snapshots (snapshot_id, hroom_id, date_added);
```

Indexes for the main query:

```
create index idx3 on snapshots (hroom_id, date_added, snapshot_id);
create index idx4 on hotel_rooms (hroom_id, name);
create index idx5 on customers (cus_id, driver_id);
create index idx6 on participants (snapshot_id, cus_id);
```

Comment: I tried your subquery with your recommended indexes. It took 0.0336 seconds in total to do it (with millions of rows of data). This part of the query is fast `SELECT snapshot_id FROM participants WHERE cus_id = 1`. The outter query is slow

Comment: It doesn't use `create index idx2 on snapshots (snapshot_id, hroom_id, date_added);` at all. Instead it uses the primary key, `snapshot_id`

Comment: This is a bit surprising. As we come with a customer ID and get the related snapshot IDs from participants, the logical next step would be to take these snapshot IDs and find rooms and dates. idx2 is a covering index, which I found likely to be used for this purpose. With idx3 the main query can quickly use the subquery result to get all snapshots and with their IDs the participants. Shouldn't bee too slow. Of course joins and aggregations cost time. Maybe your expectations on how fast this query should run are just a tad too high :-)